# Citymapper API wrapper

Tags: api, r

As a simple project to tackle during the holidays I've set to write a simple wrapper around [Citymapper's](https://citymapper.com/tools/1063/api-for-robots) api to familiarise with `httr`, `testthat` and a simple CI setup (on CircleCI).

The API mainly revolves around 2 things:

- Cheking if a given point falls within their covered areas. As on their api docs there are 2 versions of this endpoint (a second one accepts multiple inputs via a JSON payload), I've implemented 2 different functions to reflect this, no idea if it'd make sense to collapse it into one.
- Computing travel time (using public transport) between two points.

Below you can find the main methods, [here](https://github.com/andodet/citymappR) a link to the repo.

**get_travel_time.R**

```r
#' Get travel time between two points
#'
#' Computes estimated travel time between two points using public transport.
#' If \code{time} and \code{time_type} are not specified, time of travel will be assumed to be the same time at which the request is made.
#'
#' @param start_coord Geographical coordinates of the start point in WGS84 '<latitude>,<longitude>' format.
#' @param end_coord Geographical coordinates of the arrival point in WGS84 '<latitude>,<longitude>' format.
#' @param time A date & time in ISO-8601 format (e.g \code{2014-11-06T19:00:02-0500}). If omitted travel time will be computed for travel at the time of the request.
#' @param time_type Required if `time` is provided. At the moment the only defined type is `arrival`, it computes the travel time for arriving at `end_coord` at the given time.
#' @inheritParams citymappr_setup
#' @return Estimated travel time in minutes (int).
#'
#' @examples
#' \dontrun{
#' get_travel_time(start_coord = "45.448643,9.207645",
#'                 end_coord = "45.452349,9.180225")
#' }
#'
#'
#' @importFrom httr GET stop_for_status content
#' @importFrom jsonlite fromJSON
#'
#' @export
get_travel_time <- function(start_coord,
                            end_coord,
                            time="",
                            time_type="",
                            api_token = Sys.getenv("CITYMAPPER_API_TOKEN")) {


  resp <-GET(url = "https://developer.citymapper.com/api/1/traveltime/",
             query = list(
               key = api_token,
               startcoord = start_coord,
               endcoord = end_coord,
               time = time,
               time_type = time_type
             )
  )

  stop_for_status(resp)

  return(
    fromJSON(
      content(resp, "text"))$travel_time_minutes
  )

}
```

**check_coverage.R**

```r
#' Check if a point is in covered area
#'
#' Checks if a given point falls within Citymapper's covered areas.
#' It is good practice to refresh this value regularly as covered areas might change.
#'
#' @inheritParams citymappr_setup
#' @param point Geographical coordinates of the point in WGS84 \code{'<latitude>,<longitude>'} format.
#' @return A tibble containing boolean responses for each point.
#'
#' @importFrom magrittr %>%
#' @importFrom rlang .data
#' @importFrom httr GET content stop_for_status
#' @importFrom jsonlite fromJSON
#' @importFrom dplyr mutate
#' @importFrom tibble as_tibble
#'
#' @examples
#' \dontrun{
#' check_coverage("45.448643,9.207645")
#' }
#'
#' @export
check_coverage <- function(point,
                           api_token=Sys.getenv("CITYMAPPER_API_TOKEN")) {

  resp <- GET(url="https://developer.citymapper.com/api/1/singlepointcoverage/",
              query = list(key = api_token,
                           coord = point))

  stop_for_status(resp)

  return(
    fromJSON(
      content(resp, "text"))[["points"]]$covered
  )

}
```

**check_coverage_multi.R**

```r
#' Checks if multiple points are in covered area
#'
#' Checks if  multiple points fall within Citymapper's covered areas.
#' It is good practice to refresh this values regularly as covered areas might change.
#'
#' @inheritParams citymappr_setup
#' @param points Dataframe containing geographical coordinates of the start point in WGS84 \code{'<latitude>,<longitude>'} format.
#'   Columns should be set as \code{id (optional)} and \code{coord}.
#' @return A tibble containing boolean responses for each point. IDs column passed in \code{points} will be mirrored back in response.
#'
#' @examples
#' \dontrun{
#' # Make dataframes with coordinates and (optional) ids
#'
#' }
#'
#' @seealso \code{\link{check_coverage}}
#'
#' @importFrom magrittr %>%
#' @importFrom jsonlite fromJSON toJSON
#' @importFrom httr POST content stop_for_status
#' @importFrom tibble as_tibble
#'
#' @export
#TODO: there are problems with json parsin (coords are not parsed as a list)
check_coverage_multi <- function(points,
                                 api_token=Sys.getenv("CITYMAPPER_API_TOKEN")) {

  if (!is.data.frame(points)) {
    points <- as_tibble(points)
  }

  # Check if column name respect c("id", "coord") convention
  if(!all(c("coord") %in% names(points))) {
    stop("Dataframe has wrong column names, make sure they are set as c('id', 'coord')")
  }

  # Get input in required JSON format
  points$coord <- lapply(
    strsplit(as.character(points$coord), ","),
    as.numeric
  )

  cured_input <- toJSON(list(`points` = points))

  resp <- POST(paste0("https://developer.citymapper.com/api/1/coverage/?key=",
                      api_token),
               body = cured_input,
               encode="json")

  stop_for_status(resp)

  return(
    fromJSON(
      content(resp, "text"))[["points"]]
    )

}
```

Even being quite a simple package, it'd be good to understand if project structure makes sense and if there's any room for improvement.

Comment: By the way, on L41 of [`check_coverage_multi.R`](https://github.com/andodet/citymappR/blob/c0f0fd4cb1391bf425d0118353fab73e79f19e64/R/check_coverage_multi.R#L41), are you sure you don't mean `!all(c("id", "coord") %in% names(points))`?

Comment: Good questions, I am checking just for the `coord` columns as it's mandatory (`id` is optional as it'll be just mirrored back from the endpoint for quick reference). Is there a more elegant solution? I do believe I left that `if(!all(...))` there as I began checking for both fields in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think overall, it looks quite good. Some polishing is needed before you submit to CRAN (e.g. you didn't update the `Title` and `Description` fields in your `DESCRIPTION`). Below are also specific points you might want to consider.

### Structure of your specific project

- In terms of structure, I don't really understand the need of having two separate functions for checking coverage for a single point and for multiple points. I know the API has two different URLs for this but surely, it would be simpler for users if they have a single function that works no matter if they provide one or multiple points. Or am I missing something here?
- Currently, if the user didn't register an API key, they get a cryptic error message (`Forbidden (HTTP 403)`). It might be better to check if `api_token` is empty and return a more specific error message.
- You seem to import a lot of packages and functions that (as I far as I can tell) you're not using. If this is actually the case, it might be good to remove them from your dependency list.

### General package structure comments

- Add a `BugReports` field to your `DESCRIPTION` to guide users to the appropriate place to report issues and contribute patches.
- [According to CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/licenses/MIT), your `LICENSE` file should only contain two lines with your name and the year, not the full license text.
- You have non-standard files in your package root, namely `circle.yml` (should be add to `.Rbuildignore`) and `citymappR_logo.png` ([should be moved to `man/figures`](https://github.com/ropensci/rotemplate/issues/19#issuecomment-506315565)).

### Specific points relevant to API packages:

- [It is good practice to set a custom user agent for API package](https://httr.r-lib.org/articles/api-packages.html#set-a-user-agent), including your contact, so that API developers know where the requests come from and can reach you if necessary.

### Optional:

- [Your roxygen comments can use the markdown syntax](https://roxygen2.r-lib.org/articles/rd-formatting.html) if you like. Personally I prefer it as I find it more readable in its unparsed state but it's not an obligation and it's up to you.

Comment: Many thanks for you time. I don't think I'll submit it to CRAN as it is just a pet project I've developed during some free time. Thanks for the spot-on feedback, especially regarding folder structure and the custom user-agent.